# HTACCESS read url param and set cookie

Tags: .htaccess, cookies

I'm trying to read a parameter from a URL and store it in a cookie so that the website loads with the proper values.

let's say the url is:

www.abc.com/?province=QC

my cookie name is "client-province"

How can I read the value of "province" and store it in my cookie ? Is it even possible?

I'm a total noob when it comes to htaccess and I can't find anything that doesn't involve a redirect.

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)province=([a-z0-9]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=client-province:%1:abc.com:14400:/]
```

The cookie seems to be properly set, except that I thought it would prepare the cookie's value so that the website would have the correct content without having to refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so this sets the cookie correctly after getting the value from the parameter. I thought it would prevent a page reload in order for the content to adapt itself based on the cookie, but it doesn't.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)province=([a-z0-9]+)(?:&|$) 
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=client-province:%1:abc.com:14400:/]
```